# Can I open system files through the web browser URL

Tags: windows, browser, url

You can access web content by typing in windows address bar.
But can you access a file by typing it's directory in the web browser URL?
Typing in the URL something like:

```
file:///C:/
```

will let you browse your files (FTP way). In that way you can open some basic files like: txt or bmp. But other files will just download.

Is there a way or addon that will allow me to open a specific location/file on my pc through browsers url? So if I type in the URL:

```
%systemroot%/system32/appwiz.cpl
```

it will open "installed programs" window.

Answer (score 1):

For "%systemroot%/system32/appwiz.cpl" this is possible by using Internet Explorer and when you get the download dialouge, just select open.
For other browsers you will have to type "file:///C:/Windows/System32/appwiz.cpl" and select "Open" in the download dialogue.

Tested and confirmed working on XP and Win 8 with Chrome and IE

Comment: Nice! To bad that this only works (like it should) with IE. Thank you.

Comment: I had this working for me with Chrome aswell, atleast for the appwiz.cpl file by just opening it (pressing the icon on the download bar) after downloading.